# X-Scrollbar Showing Up and Contents Still Overflowing (Front-End Help Need)

Tags: html, css, frontend, web-frontend

There is an x-scrollbar on the page when it should not. Here’s a photo of what I’m describing:

[image: 0]

I don’t know where is that extra white space on the right of `.main-content` is coming from. And why the `header` and `footer` overflows the set screen width.

Plus, the background-image not showing up lol

Here is the link to the code and live site:
[Source Code](https://github.com/nabi-cloud/fotomatic)
[Live Site](https://nabi-cloud.github.io/fotomatic/)

The goal is the `header` and `footer` should not overflow so that the x-scrollbar doesn’t appear and the `.main-content` should fill the whole width of the screen size. It should be a vertical scroll page only.

I've tried checking and editing it on Chrome Dev, but still no changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with `<footer>`.

You have a combined `4rem` of horizontal `padding` between `left` and `right` indicated by `padding: 1.25rem 2rem;` which adds to the `width` of the footer.

You can either remove `width: 100%;` from the footer, or use this:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[box-sizing - CSS: Cascading Style Sheets | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

Comment: Thanks! It did solve the x-scrollbar on desktop screen view. But when the screen size is set to 450px wide. The header overflows. and the white space on the main-content is still there. Got any idea how to solve this?

Comment: @Nabi Try adding `* { box-sizing: border-box;}` as mentioned.

Comment: @Nabi It's once again horizontal `padding` on `#sign-up-cta`. If you use `* { box-sizing: borer-box;}` it should correct all of these issues because it sets how the total width and height of an element is calculated.

Comment: So I did the border-box like you said and it did solve the header and footer. Not until I deleted the padding line did the actual white spacing was gone hahaha many thanks! :))

Comment: @Nabi I don't see `*{box-sizing: border-box;}` when looking on your dev site. `*` means all elements, so that style would be applied to everything. Therefore, correcting the issues. I suggest incorporating this style correctly so you're not stuck removing `padding` on everything from here on.

Comment: Hey Kameron, I haven't committed the modified site yet haha. I'll mark this answered, thanks again!